# How Should I COUNT Tot.Num of Tours?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, having

**Table information** (Primary key are bolded):

- TOUR-GUIDE (***GuideCode**, Name, Surname, Nationality*)
- TYPE-OF-TOUR (***TourTypeCode**, Monument, Duration, City*)
- GROUP (***GroupCode**, NumberOfParticipants, Language*)
- GUIDED-TOUR-CARRIED-OUT (***GroupCode**, **Date**, **StartTime**,

  TourTypeCode, GuideCode*)

**Task:**
For each tour guide who has never guided a type of tour for French-speaking groups, show name, and surname and, for each date, the total number of types of tours guided and their total duration.

What should I do in order to COUNT the total number of TypeofTours and their total duration?

```
SELECT Name, Surname 
FROM TOUR-GUIDE TG, GUIDED-TOUR-CARRIED-OUT GTCO, TYPE-OF-TOUR TOT2
WHERE GTCO.GuideCode = TG.GuideCode, AND TOT2.TourTypeCode = GTCO.TourTypeCode
  AND GuideCode NOT IN
                (SELECT GuideCode
                 FROM GROUP P, GUIDED-TOUR-CARRIED-OUT GTCO2
                 WHERE GTCO2.GroupCode = G.GroupCode
                   AND Language = 'French')
GROUP BY TG.Name, TG.Surname, GTCO.Date
HAVING COUNT(*) =
            (SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM TYPE-OF-TOUR TOT
             GROUP BY TourTypeCode, Duration)
```

Comment: Also, please let me know if there are anything I should change in the way I ask the question. (This is my first question in stackoverflow.:)

Comment: Your image is not showing. Can you please write down the requirement?

Comment: @ShuchitaRahamn I edited the question. Could you please check?

Comment: Could you please setup an example here containing your table structure and sample inuput data? https://dbfiddle.uk/ Also the expected outcome would be nice.

Comment: @JonasMetzler unfortunately I have not given any expected outcome or table structure. This is the total amount of information I am able to access.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know the value of your table I wasn't able to run my query.
If my solution doesn't work let me know.

**Solution:**

```
with cte as(
Select Duration, Date, GuideCode
From GROUP a 
left join GUIDED-TOUR-CARRIED-OUT b on a.GROUP = b.GROUP
Left join TYPE-OF-TOUR c on b.TourTypeCode = c.TourTypeCode
Where Language != 'French'   
)

Select Date, 
       Name,
       Surname, 
       sum(Duration),
       count(GuideCode) 
From TOUR-GUIDE a left join cte on a.GuideCode = cte.GuideCode
Group by 
Date, GuideCode, Name, Surname
```